# Why can't Google speech diarization distinguish between two different voices?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm mystified by Google speech diarization--it doesn't seem to be able to differentiate between two very dissimilar voices (a man and a woman).

The attached code processes the publicly available "medical conversation" audio file; it's a good recording, at 16 kHz, but diarization still identifies both speakers as "speaker 1."

```
man:
speaker 1 @ 0:00:00.600000   | 0.91 | hello
speaker 1 @ 0:00:02.600000   | 0.99 | good
speaker 1 @ 0:00:02.800000   | 0.99 | morning

woman:
speaker 1 @ 0:00:02.900000   | 0.97 | good
speaker 1 @ 0:00:04.200000   | 0.99 | morning

man:
speaker 1 @ 0:00:04.300000   | 0.99 | so
speaker 1 @ 0:00:06.100000   | 0.99 | tell
speaker 1 @ 0:00:06.700000   | 0.99 | me
speaker 1 @ 0:00:06.800000   | 0.99 | what's
speaker 1 @ 0:00:07.200000   | 0.99 | going
speaker 1 @ 0:00:07.300000   | 0.99 | on
```

I've played around with the various [SpeakerDiarizationConfig parameters](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#SpeakerDiarizationConfig), but with no real improvement.

Note also that although this example uses the [Asynchronous speech recognizer](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize), I get similarly poor results with the streaming recognizer.

Does anybody have tips for yielding better results?

```
from google.cloud import speech

def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""

    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

    # https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices#speech_transcribe_diarization_beta-python                                                                                                  
    diarization_config = speech.SpeakerDiarizationConfig(
        enable_speaker_diarization=True,
        min_speaker_count=1,
        max_speaker_count=3,
    )
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code="en-US",
        enable_word_confidence=True,
        diarization_config = diarization_config,
        #model="phone_call",                                                                                                                                                                                  
    )

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through                                                                                                                                  
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.                                                                                                                                                  
    for result in response.results:
        #print(f"is_final: {result.is_final}")                                                                                                                                                                
        for n in range(len(result.alternatives)):
            print(f"Alternative {n}")
            alt = result.alternatives[n]
            print(f"Transcript:\n {alt.transcript}")

        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.                                                                                                                                      
        alt = result.alternatives[0]
        print(f"Transcript 0: {alt.transcript}")
        print(f"Confidence 0: {alt.confidence}")
        for word in alt.words:
            print(f"speaker {word.speaker_tag} @ {str(word.start_time):16} | {word.confidence:2.2} | {word.word}")
        # #                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    print("\n")


if __name__=="__main__":
    audio_uri="gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/medical_conversation_2.wav"
    transcribe_gcs(audio_uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where diarization didn't work. But that happens because each voice where in a specific channel, so I had to differentiate the speakers by the channel:

```
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
    enable_separate_recognition_per_channel=True,
    audio_channel_count=2,
    language_code="en-US",
)
```

This option worked for me. In addition you can use the enhanced where will take more time to process but can give you better results:

```
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    ...
    use_enhanced=True,
    model="phone_call",
)
```

Comment: Thank you, saved my bacon with the audio channel stuff. although model "video" worked best for me.